# Searchable dynamic combobox WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, combobox

I'm attempting to create a searchable combobox where the dropdown items (in an ObservableCollection) update as the user text.

For example:
Let's say I have a list of all the cities in the world (10,000+), something which is too large to display in a drodown list. This list (max 100 items) is retrieved through an API which sends a search term within the GET request.
So as the user searches for a specific city, the observable collection is updated to show the related search terms and the data-bound combobox is updated.

When search = "", returns first 100 cities (those beginning with A) from API. Observablecollection/combobox is updated to show.
When search = "London", returns x cities with London in the name from API. Observablecollection/combobox is updated to show.

Currently, I have the following code to update the observable collection when the search value is changed (this works using INotifyPropertyChanged). However when the collection and by association the data-bound combobox is updated, the user's search term is removed.

```
public ObservableCollection<string> cities { get; set; }

private string searchString;

public string SearchString
{
    get
    {
        return searchString;
    }
    set
    {
        searchString = value;
        // Call OnPropertyChanged whenever the property is updated
        OnPropertyChanged("SearchString");
    }
}

// Create the OnPropertyChanged method to raise the event 
protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
{
    if (name == "SearchString")
    {
        UpdateCitiesDropdown();
    }

    PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
    if (handler != null)
    {
        handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));

    }
}

public async void UpdateCitiesDropdown()
{    
    // Retrieve new cities
    List<string> newCities = await GetCities(searchString);

    // Save old cities to remove (from observable collection)
    List<string> oldCities = cities.ToList<string>();

    foreach (string city in oldCities )
    {
        cities.Remove(city );
    }

    // Add new
    foreach (string city in newCities)
    {
        cities.Add(city );
    }
}
```

This the current combobox with it's bound data.

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding cities}" Text="{Binding SearchString, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" IsEditable="True"/>
```

Is there any way to update the observable collection and have the combobox updated without removing the user search?

Comment: The issue is that you are calling async method from sync setter. Btw. you are calling async method in a sync way, UpdateCitiesDropdown should return Task not void if it is async. When user type the search text UpdateCitiesDropdown method will be called multiple times. Async updates of combobox will be a challenge. Try to search it on SO.

Comment: @user2250152 Just running a test with breaks I can confirm that with each character change in the search string, the function is only called once. However, on the final call where the user selects a dropdown item, the search is set to blank ("").

Answer (score 0):

The text which is preselected in the `ComboBox` is the text of the currently selected item.
In `UpdateCitiesDropdown` method you are removing all old cities including the selected item. That's the reason why the search is set to blank later.

The solution can be to add `SelectedCity` property to your view model.

```
private string selectedCity;
public string SelectedCity
{
    get { return selectedCity; }
    set
    {
        selectedCity = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("SelectedCity");
    }
}
```

Bind the property to `ComboBox's` `SelectedItem`

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding cities}" Text="{Binding SearchString, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCity}" IsEditable="True"/>
```

And modify `UpdateCitiesDropdown` method not to remove `SelectedItem` from `cities` collection

```
...
List<string> oldCities = cities.Where(x => x != SelectedCity).ToList<string>();
...
foreach (string city in newCities)
{
    if (city != SelectedCity)
    {
        cities.Add(city);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like @user2250152 stated, the problem happens when you remove all the cities from your collection. Then the SearchString value is set to empty string.

Here is my solution to this problem:

- You introduce a new bool variable clearingItems to indicate that you
  are clearing items (cities).
- Then you change your SearchString property setter to only set to new
  value if clearingItems is false.
- And last you write a method for clearing items (cities) where you set
  clearingItems flag and you call that in UpdateCitiesDropdown.

So the final code would look like this:

```
public ObservableCollection<string> cities { get; set; }
private bool clearingItems;   
private string searchString;

public string SearchString
{
    get
    {
        return searchString;
    }
    set
    {
        if(!clearingItems)
        {
            searchString = value;
            // Call OnPropertyChanged whenever the property is updated
            OnPropertyChanged("SearchString");
        }
    }
}

// Create the OnPropertyChanged method to raise the event 
protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
{
    if (name == "SearchString")
    {
        UpdateCitiesDropdown();
    }

    PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
    if (handler != null)
    {
        handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));

    }
}

public async void UpdateCitiesDropdown()
{    
    // Retrieve new cities
    List<string> newCities = await GetCities(searchString);

    ClearItems();

    // Add new
    foreach (string city in newCities)
    {
        cities.Add(city );
    }
}

private void ClearItems()
{
    clearingItems = true;
    cities.Clear();
    clearingItems = false;
}
```

Your xaml code stays the same.